# Whats wrong with this UIViewController? Swift 3, Loading Data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit

I am simply trying to load this parsed Bitcoin price data into the tableview. I have it set to a test string right now but that still isn't working.  I have triple checked everything in the storyboard so I am assuming it's something in this code:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import AlamofireObjectMapper
import ObjectMapper

class Response: Mappable {
    var data: [Amount]?
    required init?(map: Map){

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        data <- map["data"]
    }
}

class Amount: Mappable {
    var data : String?

    required init?(map: Map){

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        data <- map["data.amount"]
    }
}

let mount = [String]()

let am = [String]()

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, 
UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = "test"

        return cell
    }

    func Call_bitcoin(){
        let url = "https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/BTC-USD/buy"
        Alamofire.request(url).responseObject{ (response: DataResponse<Amount>) in
            let mount = response.result.value
            let am = mount?.data
            print(am)

        }
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        Call_bitcoin()

        self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return am.count
    }  


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("You tapped cell number \(indexPath.row).")
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, please improve your code formatting. Very difficult to read as is... thanks!

Comment: Thanks, fixed the formatting. Shout out to Anton!

Comment: Is your `TableView` loaded? I mean, can you see the cell separator lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to call the method `reloadData()` inside the callback of the Alamofire request. This is because Alamofire do an asynchronous call.

Then, you will have the `Call_bitcoin` like this:

```
func Call_bitcoin() {
    let url = "https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/BTC-USD/buy"
    Alamofire.request(url).responseObject{ (response: DataResponse<Amount>) in
        let mount = response.result.value
        let am = mount?.data
        print(am)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Also, you can refactor your `viewDidLoad` method, because you don't need to reloadData of the tableview (You are already doing it on the `Call_bitcoin` 
 method). So, the viewDidLoad will be like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    Call_bitcoin()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reload tableView while data fetched successfully.

Because alamofire do aschronus call.

```
func Call_bitcoin(){
          let url = "https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/BTC-USD/buy"         
Alamofire.request(url).responseObject
{ (response: DataResponse<Amount>) in 
      let mount = response.result.value                    
     let am = mount?.data print(am)
   tblView.reloadData()
 } 
}
```

***current you passed empty array to numberOfRowInSection so you need to pass number of count as below***

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10 //because your am.count empty
    }
```

Comment: I'm not even using the data from the call in my tableView yet. I am using a test string 'cell.textLabel?.text = "test"`
'

Comment: yes but you passed empty array to numberRowInSection ...other wise pass hard coded integer number .

Comment: Thank you! Sorry I picked the above answer. He just did not have as much rep here! Im sure you understand:)

Comment: it is not valid . i have given answer first then my answer deserve accepting . rep doesn't matter here .